# Type doesn't look smooth when importing Nib file with NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, antialiasing

I'm importing a seperate nib file using a `NSViewController`. In my windowController, the nib is loaded using the following code:

```
_schedulesViewController = [[SchedulesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Schedules" bundle:nil];
[_inspectorView addSubview:[_schedulesViewController view]];
```

There is one problem: the text from the schedules nib file doesn't look smooth. It seems that there is a scaling problem. Here's a screen capture:

[image]

The text just doesn't look anti-aliased. In xCode all the labels are looking bad too. What could be wrong?

Comment: Oke I have found the solution to my problem. Just disable 'Core Animation Layer' for the view you have problems with. You can find this checkbox under the View Effects Inspector.
Now the text looks smooth again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oke I have found the solution to my problem. Just disable 'Core Animation Layer' for the view you have problems with. You can find this checkbox under the View Effects Inspector. Now the text looks smooth again.

Comment: Brilliant! One of my views showed the exact same behaviour and had me stumped for weeks now. I was about to redo the whole thing when I read your post. You saved me a LOT of work :-)